# Ajax Request Jquery on IE9, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, request

I have a rest api in one server and a application that uses the rest web services in another.

Rest api server is a https and the other it's http.

I need to call the web service to get the json data, but in IE9 when i make an ajax request every time gives me an error. (could be cors problem).

To do the request i need to set up the headers on request because they are need to authentication.

In FF works well.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'param1': param1,
        'param2': param2,
        'param3': param3,
        'param4': param4
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fails");
    }
});
```

How can i fix this problem? I really need to run this app in IE.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Whats the jQuery vrsion?

Comment: 'It doesn't work' isn't enough information. Have you checked the console for errors? Is the endpoint being hit?

Comment: If it was **CORS** problem then it would have not worked in `FF` too because **CORS** isn't browser specific rather its `request` specific

Comment: Does the `"Fails"` alert pop up? If so, what are the values of `status` and `errorThrown`

Comment: In the error console i'm getting only error message, nothing more.

Comment: I'm using jquery v1.11.2

Comment: "Fails" alert popup appears, but the console.log only shows error

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support CORS without a shim and IE10 only has limited support.

https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

Comment: I already had read that possibility, but i need to use custom headers on my request, and on that way i'm not sure if it is possible. I guess not.

Comment: The first part of the answer was the essential part of the answer. IE9 does not support it so there is no answer other than pointing to a patch someone has created to do what the version of the browser doesn't do natively. I have had the same issue in the past and one way (although not a great way) is to have your ajax function hit a web method in your code behind if you're using .NET which makes the call from HttpClient, WebClient, etc. Again, not ideal but it's how I've gotten around the issue in the past.

Comment: The error you're getting in the console is most likely an OPTIONS error which is the preflight request. Use your ajax to call a code behind method and add your custom headers there. This would be for IE versions under 11 so just do a check and route it to the code behind method if it is one of the unsupported versions.